# RDLC Importing Data From Excel Or PDF

Tags: .net, import, reporting, rdlc

I have an Excel and also PDF file containing a table with multiple columns and many rows with bold text and background color styling. What I'm trying to do is find a way to import this into an RDLC report so I do not have to create a table and type it all in manually which will take hours.

I don't want to save it as an image and throw it on that way as the text when zoomed will not be clear. I asked the developer that made the original application how he did it and he told me he saved the Excel file as a PDF and imported it into the report. The original application was coded in VBA so I can't see why an Access VBA application can do this but a .NET application cannot. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely he ran Excel through VBA, for this same approach you can use Interop in .NET but i'm not sure that you can import the PDF file to the RLDC report, if you're interested here is an example of how to save an Excel file to PDF using interop: [Saving file as PDF by using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13233359/saving-file-as-pdf-by-using-microsoft-office-interop-excel), note that you need Excel 2007 or newer for this to work.

There is another approach that may suit you better, specially if the Excel file have a table like structure, and is connecting using OLE DB to Excel to use Excel as a database, for this, you can find appropiate connections strings here: http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel

Comment: Converting the Excel file to PDF is not the issue, it's adding an already saved PDF into a report rather than having to type in all the data from each row/column into a tablix on the report from the PDF.

Comment: Then you may better try the second approach i told you, this have the benefit that will let you use the Excel file as a data source and you will be able to give it a different format in the final report.

Answer (score 0):

**Try THIS CODE**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;


namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            ExtractTextFromPDFPage("c:\sample.pdf", 1);
        }

        public void ExtractTextFromPDFPage(string pdfFile, int pageNumber)
        {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(pdfFile);
            string text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, pageNumber);
            try { reader.Close(); }
            catch { }
            richTextBox1.Text = text;
        }
    }
}
```

**Download the iTextSharp dll from** 
http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_itextsharp/releases/
and **Add to Reference**

Comment: JUST DOWNLOAD THIS iTextSharp DLLs FROM  http://en.sourceforge.jp/projects/sfnet_itextsharp/releases/
AND ADD IT TO YOUR C# APPLICATION. AND PUT THIS CODE IN ANY CLASS. AND CALL THE FUNCTION. TYPE A VALID PDF FILE PATH. I TESTED AND WORKING IT FINE.